# Loop Problem: Displays same set of post for all categories

Tags: loop, categories

So, I have 2 loops, one inside the other. The first to get the category titles, the second to display a few recent post from that category.

Problem: Category titles display fine, but the recent post for each category are the same.

What I end up with is this:

Category-1
Post-1, Post-2, Post-3

Category-2
Post-1, Post-2, Post-3

Category-3
Post-1, Post-2, Post-3

etc..

CODE:

```
$catArgs = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'exclude' => '106'
);

$postArgs = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'showposts' => '4',
);


$categories = get_categories($catArgs);
if($categories){
foreach($categories as $category) {
        $my_query = new WP_Query($postArgs); ?>
            <div class="panel"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"><a href="<? echo get_category_link( $category->term_id );?>" title="<? echo $category->cat_name; ?>"><? echo $category->cat_name; ?></a></span>
            <div><? echo category_description( $category->term_id ); ?></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="large-block-grid-4">
                <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><? the_post_thumbnail(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul> 
<? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the same arguments to retrieve every set of posts. You have alter the arguments dynamically to reflect the current category.

```
$categories = get_categories($catArgs);
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $postArgs['cat'] = $category->cat_ID;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($postArgs);
        // ...
```

Untested, and I am away from my dev server but that should be pretty close. You will have overlap for recent posts if several show up in multiple categories and I would suggest passing an `ignore_sticky_posts` argument to `WP_Query` as well.

Comment: +1. Also: `wp_reset_postdata()` would be appropriate here as well.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata` after the `foreach` loop would be more appropriate. `wp_reset-postdata` inside the `foreach` would be overkill as `$my_query->the_post();` take care of the same things.